# Mapped type lookup doesn't require object type to be set correctly with function returned from another function

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to implement a function that takes an event name and a properties object that can vary with the name of the event. The function that takes the event name and properties object is returned from another function, but typescript doesn't seem to be enforcing the type of the properties object correctly.

I'm using typescript 3.7.2.

I'm implementing the enum for the event name, the properties object types and the record for the properties like this:

```js
export enum EventName {
  foo = 'foo',
  bar = 'bar',
  baz = 'baz',
}

interface IProperties {

}

interface IMoreProperties extends IProperties {
  prop1: string
}

export interface EventProperties extends Record<EventName, IProperties> {
  foo: IProperties;
  bar: IMoreProperties;
  baz: IProperties;
}
```

When I use a function that doesn't return another function it correctly type checks that I've set the correct fields on the properties object:

```js
function test<E extends EventProperties, K extends keyof E>(eventName: K, properties: E[K]): void {
}

test('foo', {});
// Correctly requires that property be set.
test('bar', {prop1: 'test'});
```

However when I return the function from another function it doesn't properly enforce that the properties object should have 'prop1' set:

```js
function returnFunctionTest<E extends EventProperties, K extends keyof E>(
): (eventName: K, properties: E[K]) => void
{
  function eventFunction(eventName: K, properties: E[K]): void { }

  return eventFunction;
}

const testFunc = returnFunctionTest<EventProperties, keyof EventProperties>();
testFunc('foo', {});
// Should error because it doesn't have 'prop1'
testFunc('bar', {});
```

How do I force the returned function to type check correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the following call,

```
const testFunc = returnFunctionTest<EventProperties, keyof EventProperties>();
```

you have manually specified the type parameters `E` and `K` to be the widest possible types they can be.  The compiler dutifully uses those types for `E` and `K`, and the returned function is of type

```
/* const testFunc: (
    eventName: "foo" | "bar" | "baz", 
    properties: IProperties | IMoreProperties
  ) => void; */
```

That function type does not restrict `properties` to be of a type corresponding to the particular value of `eventName`.  It has been widened too far to be of use.

Note that this particular issue has nothing to do with returning a function vs returning a value, since you could do the same thing with your working example.  Manually specify the type parameters, and you get what you specify:

```
test<EventProperties, keyof EventProperties>('bar', {}); // no error
```

---

Instead of manually specifying the type parameters, you probably want to let the compiler *infer* them.  But, (and this might be part of the problem you're having), this won't work either:

```
const testFuncInfer = returnFunctionTest();
/* const testFuncInfer: (
     eventName: "foo" | "bar" | "baz", 
    properties: IProperties | IMoreProperties
   ) => void; */
```

The problem is that `returnFunctionTest()` takes no arguments from which `E` and `K` can be inferred.  Your `test()` function doesn't have that problem because it takes two parameters corresponding to `E` and `K`.

And you don't really *want* to choose `E` and `K` when you call `returnFunctionTest()` (well, `K` anyway), do you?  You'd like to *defer* that choice to when the returned function is itself called.  So the most obvious solution here (depending on your use case) is to move the generic type parameters off of `returnFunctionTest()` and onto the function it returns.  So instead of a generic function returning a specific function, you have a specific function returning a generic function.  Like this:

```
function returnFunctionTest2(
): <E extends EventProperties, K extends keyof E>(eventName: K, properties: E[K]) => void {
  function eventFunction<E extends EventProperties, K extends keyof E>(
    eventName: K, properties: E[K]): void { }
  return eventFunction;
}
```

And you can test that it works:

```
const testFunc2 = returnFunctionTest2();
testFunc2('foo', {}); // okay
testFunc2('bar', {}); // error! prop1 is missing
testFunc2('bar', { prop1: "better" }); // okay now
```

Looks good to me.

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#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-Mi0VjmGNcfjxnQw76EBDQz6I4gCz0oTC4cmK5gq3m6wS1TkaP7A5dwbg2+GLgd7G1EKkrjG58JJ0G577ozdLda-Kb-lmD-3RiCaYr12GyRwHVfiTfTsr7f1SHqlxdVyS5wZELQWibrKU47h2e6ko+tIAFRwMuP7Pro-6AVAyQ5jENAtt2xDJAARBwuFwAAPnAuGiIRJFkQQUi4f0Eg0OKew7OetgkQYyyrOWNj0ZiNZwCOsxwNBtK8EcTYdlyIHbuJUYxgATOheZxvUCblLgh42Km8bpnAmYWqCM4aEWvZljMNiVhivFMLWeKjhI3rztOrYyYgyn3GpTxca8JZpj8J76ehmFYUZPYln2XkWViOK2WQuoSFuTmzi5i65JQ8HwL+YZycBAbSe2smpApj6ZacCnkpw76Os6EDfAQfzXqkc5lSqlU0k6DLutAACEpnxEUtioKo1jWJkDUwE1r5iO+vV4VKMDOIRVUMjVdUuhAADuVBAA)

Comment: Thanks! Random question: is there a better title for this? I found it hard to google this and would like to make it easy for people to find.